# Failed to start Quarkus in dev mode for multi module project: DevModeContext.getApplicationRoot() is null

Tags: java, quarkus

*I've updgraded to 2.14.1 Final, first version of the question was with 2.13.3 Final, also tried with 2.13.4.Final*

Last update: I'm on Quarkus 2.14.1 Final version.

I switched my project to a multi-module structure, and now I cannot run quarkus in *dev* mode. I can build the project fine, but when I run `quarkus dev` I get this error:

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.14.1.Final:dev (default-cli) @ my-project ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeContext$ModuleInfo.getMain()" because the return value of "io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeContext.getApplicationRoot()" is null
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:90)
at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
```

Do I need to tell Quarkus where are now the endpoints or something else?

How to reproduce it (I guess the Java version is not important):

1 - Run:

```
quarkus create app --maven --java=19.0.1 --wrapper --package-name=com.myproject
```

This creates the `code-with-quarkus` project.

2 - Then add a new module to the project, for example, `ìnfrastructure-web`.

3 - Move the source code generated in step one to the module. This means moving `com.myproject.GreetingResource` to the new module `src/main/java` folder.

4 - Run:

```
mvn clean install && quarkus dev
```

5 - You get the error I got.

Here is a project with this problem: https://github.com/eyp/quarkus-dev-start-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to move the configuration of the Maven plugin `quarkus-maven-plugin` to the section `pluginManagement`of the parent's `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Afterwards, add just the plugin to the module, in this case the module which contains the endpoints (resource class).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This way, it'll be possible to run `quarkus dev` goal from the main folder of the project.

Comment: I get the same error with 2.13.4.Final

Comment: Btw, the error message is not the same as the Issue you pointed me to. I don't have any Main class, so I'm not using @QuarkusMain or QuarkusApplication anywhere.

Comment: Just tried right now with 2.14.1.Final, but still same issue. I think instead of a bug, or something, it could be a config problem?

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda do you have a project you could share to reproduce the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I've added the steps to reproduce the problem in the main question.

Comment: Thanks for the details @EduardoYáñezParareda. The reason it fails is because you have `quarkus-maven-plugin` with `build` and other goals configured for a module with packaging `pom`. If you remove the plugin or its execution config from the parent POM, it'll work.

Comment: I opened a PR to skip the dev goal execution for modules with packaging `pom` https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/29420. Thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: Well, in fact I didn't have anything configured about `quarkus-maven-plugin` in the module, but it worked for me adding in the pom.xml of the module the plugin with the `dev` goal, and letting the rest as it was in the parent module.

Comment: I've added in the question a link to a project I've created that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I don't see adding the plugin config you mentioned to the infrastructure-web module solving the issue. It also depends on in which dir `mvn quarkus:dev` is launched. If it is launched from the root project dir, the first module to process will be `core-with-quarkus`. Given that it has the quarkus-maven-plugin configured, it will fail on `quarkus:dev`, what's configured in the `infrastructure-web` is irrelevant. However, launching `quarkus:dev` from the `infrastructure-web` will work because it inherits a proper `quarkus-maven-plugin` from the parent. Now here is what would be recommended...

Comment: Move the `quarkus-maven-plugin` in the parent POM from `build/plugins` under `build/pluginManagement/plugins`. In the `infrastucture-web` add
+    <build>
+      <plugins>
+        <plugin>
+          <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
+          <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
+        </plugin>
+      </plugins>
+    </build>
Now you'll be able to launch `quarkus:dev` from the root as well as from the `infrastructure-web`. Hope that helps.

Comment: In the project I uploaded to GitHub I didn't added the plugin in the config of the module to show how it couldn't be started with `quarkus dev`

Comment: Thanks Alexey, it worked like a charm. I've edited your answer with the complete explanation.